# Is there a Maven Report showing Ohloh statistics?

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-plugin

Does anybody know if there is a Maven 2 plugin for including [Ohloh](https://www.ohloh.net/) statistics/widgets as a report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is no plugin allowing to generate a report with Ohloh's widgets. However, you could add a simple xdoc page to you website and include ohloh's `<script>` snippet in it. You need to use the [xdoc](http://maven.apache.org/doxia/references/xdoc-format.html) format for that, it is not possible with apt (see [DOXIA-349](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/DOXIA-349)).

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know you could do that using the xdoc plugin. Never bothered to take a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve that using the APT format, but that requires writing a custom Doxia macro to generate the HTML code with the  tag.